# Animation nodes list remove bug?

Tags: animation-nodes

Maybe this is meant not to work but when I try to remove an element from a `polygon indices list`, the an shows me an error. Same thing if I try to loop to fake a list copy

[image]

Here for example I want to remove the 4th and seventh faces from the polygon index lists, and it shows me the red border.

Can someone explain why this is happening? I don't see any clear reason.
Also the `remove list element` node works perfectly for edge indices and vertices locations

I am using a cython version of an, maybe this is the problem

Comment: I think this is part of the Cython implementation and polygon index list is missing some item accessors (maybe) and that should be reported https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 polygon indices in the list, their elements indices ranges between 0 and 7.

When you removed the polygon indices at index 4, you actually removed the 5th element not the the 4th (because indices starts from zero). Anyway, now you have 7 polygon indices that their elements indices ranges between 0 and 6, you are trying to remove the element at index 7 (8th element) which doesn't exist. Thats why there is an error, not sure why it is fatal though.

So, if you want to remove the 5th and 7th element, remove the element at index 4, then remove the element at index 6.

Comment: thanks for your answer Omar Ahmad, this was a mistake from me, but actually it didn't work either if I removed only the item at index 4. I reported the issue in on github, hopefully it will get fixed soon. I think as lemon said, this is part of the Cython implementation (though I didn't try in the master version)

Comment: the error show in the console: `Subscript deletion not supported by animation_nodes.data_structures.lists.polygon_indices_list.PolygonIndicesList`